# How to enable Show Desktop in Alt-Tab for classic themes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, alt-tab

`Show Desktop` item does not appear in <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> if the theme is not Windows 7 Basic.

Comment: How about pressing Windows+D instead?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for the win.

Microsoft should make a comprehensive <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> customisation program for things like this.

You could choose icons only, icon size, thumbnail and icons, thumbnail size, group explorer windows, show desktop processor usage, gadget popups, etc.